# Call WINDOWS .BAT from another windows .BAT with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to call a windows .bat from another .bat file with parameters.

Can you provide me an example for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [call batch file from another passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883500/call-batch-file-from-another-passing-parameters), [How to call a batch file from another batch file with parameters that contain spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224586/how-to-call-a-batch-file-from-another-batch-file-with-parameters-that-contain-sp), [How to Pass Command Line Parameters in Batch File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your main .bat file:

call anotherwinbatfile.bat param1 param2 param3

anotherwinbatfile.bat is the .bat file you want to call and paramX are your parameters.